# Creating a Custom Column based on two column's values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Order #  Item    Item Rejected   Pass/Fail   Order Pass
1        Glass   Yes             Fail        Fail
1        Ball    No              Pass        Fail
1        Shoe    No              Pass        Fail
1        Sock    No              Pass        Fail
2        Shoe    No              Pass        Pass
2        Sock    No              Pass        Pass
3        Glass   No              Pass        Fail
3        Shoe    Yes             Fail        Fail
3        Sock    No              Pass        Fail
```

Does anyone know a way to create that last column to determine if one row value in column 4("Pass/Fail") for each order in column 1(Order #) has a fail, then the whole order fails per the example above?

Comment: That makes little sense, because pass/fail is not a property of each individual row but of an order as a whole. It can be selected in a query, if that's what you're after (`MIN([Pass/Fail]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order #])`, determining how this works is left as an exercise to the reader), but adding it to the table itself would be distinctly unnatural (and it would require triggers to maintain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean in a query, then just simply:

```
SELECT *, MIN([Pass/Fail] OVER (PARTITION BY [Order #]) AS [Order Pass]
  FROM yourTableName
```

will do the trick. This calculates the minimum of that column across rows that share the same Order #, and we just use the fact that Fail comes earlier when sorted than Pass, hence `MIN`.

If you want to have this accessible permanently, you can't just add a field like that to a table, but you can create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW OrdersWithStatus
AS
SELECT * -- don't use * in your code, best name all the columns individually
     , MIN([Pass/Fail] OVER (PARTITION BY [Order #]) AS [Order Pass]
  FROM yourTableName
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! This seems to be a great way to do it, but unfortunately, the column [Pass/Fail] I am referencing in this is a custom column that was created using a case clause. Is there a way to still extract the min value from a custom column?

Comment: You mean like `CASE WHEN ... THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS [Pass/Fail]`? Sure, either wrap the outer query in a CTE, or just simply stick that CASE into the MIN function, e.g. `MIN(CASE .... END) OVER (....)`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a window'd aggregate might be what you're after?

```
select *, Min([pass/fail]) over(partition by orderNo) as [Order Pass]
from t
```